# Worksheet_Calculate Script error when switched off that tab

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vbscript

I created the following script to display different colored shapes based on the number when a data query refreshes, and it works but when I switch off the tab or open another workbook it gives an error when refreshing saying object not found and highlights the following line:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 16").TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 1
```

I figured it was because of the "ActiveSheet" reference so I replaced it with the actual worksheet name and it still works but still give the error.

```
Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("TextBox 16").TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 1
```

What am I doing wrong here? Also, if you see any code that can be simplified, my VBS skills are not the best. The code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim Xrg As Range, Yrg As Range

Set Xrg = Range("K31")
Set Yrg = Range("K32")

For Each aCell In Xrg
    If Not Intersect(Xrg, Range("K31")) Is Nothing Then
        If Range("K31").Value = 0 Then
            If Rows("25:25").EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            Rows("25:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
            ElseIf Range("K31").Value <> 0 Then
            If Rows("25:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
            Rows("25:25").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
For Each aCell In Yrg
    If Range("K32").Value < 55 Then
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("TextBox 16").TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 2
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("TextBox 43").TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 2
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 1").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 2").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 3").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 4").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 5").Visible = False
    End If
    If Range("K32").Value >= 55 And Range("K32").Value < 65 Then
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("TextBox 16").TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 2
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("TextBox 43").TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 2
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 1").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 2").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 3").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 4").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 5").Visible = False
    End If
    If Range("K32").Value >= 65 And Range("K32").Value < 75 Then
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("TextBox 16").TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 1
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("TextBox 43").TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 1
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 1").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 2").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 3").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 4").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 5").Visible = False
    End If
    If Range("K32").Value >= 75 And Range("K32").Value < 85 Then
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("TextBox 16").TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 2
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("TextBox 43").TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 2
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 1").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 2").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 3").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 4").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 5").Visible = False
    End If
    If Range("K32").Value >= 85 Then
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("TextBox 16").TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 2
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("TextBox 43").TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 2
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 1").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 2").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 3").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 4").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 5").Visible = True
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I think I actually fixed it myself. Didn't think to just remove the references altogether!

Comment: One suggestion would be to do a `SELECT CASE` on `Range("K32").Value` instead of all the `IF` statements.

Comment: Could you give an example of how I would use "SELECT CASE". I've googled it and can't really wrap my head around it?

Comment: I've posted an example of how you could do it below.

Answer (score 0):

One improvement that you can make to your code is to replace your `IF` statements with `SELECT CASE` and initialize your formatting prior which makes it easier to see what is being changed for each case.

```
Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("TextBox 16").TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 2
Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("TextBox 43").TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 2
Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 1").Visible = False
Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 2").Visible = False
Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 3").Visible = False
Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 4").Visible = False
Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 5").Visible = False

Select Case Range("K32").Value
    Case Is < 55
       Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 1").Visible = True
    Case 55 To 64
       Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 2").Visible = True
    Case 65 to 74
       Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("TextBox 16").TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 1
       Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("TextBox 43").TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 1
       Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 3").Visible = True
    Case 75 to 84
       Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 4").Visible = True
    Case Is > 84
       Worksheets("Outbound").Shapes("Util 5").Visible = True
End Select
```